# What API can we use to fetch a set of directions to reach a particular destination

Tags: here-api

I want to get directions from some source to some destination. If we pass geocodes as input. Which api can I use to fulfill this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There are different possibilities available from REST or API interfaces as well as for different vehicle types etc. 
I would suggest to start here with this overview: https://developer.here.com/products/routing-and-navigation

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have been using routing API for quite a while. It gives very detailed info of navigation like "Head toward <street> and go for <distance> meters" "Head towards......." e.t.c. What I actually need is a precise and crisp response which can be summarized. So, I wonder if there is some other API that can respond with some similar information.